# Wireless connects to network, but there is no internet

Tags: wireless, 13.04

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on Asus M50V laptop. It connected to my wireless network, but there is no internet. I can see that laptop got its IP number and is connected.

ping command is not working even if I write IP directly. Even router's IP.

All my other devices have internet on that wireless network.

What can I do to find where is the problem?

Comment: Did you check your DNS settings? Try setting them to `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`

Comment: i tried that now, but i see now that ping is not working even if type IP there

Comment: Is the IP address of the laptop in the same IP range as your network? You might be getting a connection but no IP address assigned by the router and falling back to a self-assigned IP address (usually starts with 164.x.x.x)

Comment: yes the IP is assigned, its 192.168.0.101 (i see it in ifconfig under wlan0), my desktop computer has 192.168.0.100 and there are 2 other mobile devices that work too.

Comment: Is your default gateway and netmask alright? Does `ping` give any error messages? Is there any non-zero invalid field in `iwconfig`?

Comment: Please, edit your answer to include the output of `ifconfig -a` and `route -n`. And what do you mean by "the ping command doesn't work, even if you type the IP there"? Post the output of that ping, and the output of pinging your router.